# How to instantiate, by the standard, a class template containing nested subclass templates

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

There is a template declaration

```
template<class C> struct Data {
    template<typename T> struct Item1 {
        void Test() {
        }
    };
};
```

Using MSVC v19.28 with the compile option /std:c++latest, I tried to instantiate the template as follows:

```
template<class C> struct Data {
    template<typename T> struct Item1 {
        void Test() {
        }
    };
};

template <class C> struct MyData : Data<C> {
    MyData::Item1<int> item10;              // (1)
};

struct S;

MyData<S> dataS;
```

The code was compiled successfully with MSVC (see the [link](https://godbolt.org/z/n3rveGMnM)), but gcc 11.1 and clang 12.0.0 could not compile it (links for [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/sb69K8cs6) and [clang](https://godbolt.org/z/3EWfTrxWK))

I tried to instantiate the template using different declarations

```
template <class C> struct MyData : Data<C> {
    MyData::Item1<int> item10;              // (1)
    Data<C>::Item1<int> item11;             // (2)
    Data<C>::template Item1<int> item12;    // (3)
};
```

MSVC compiles all of them, but gcc and clang do not.

I have "found" a [solution](https://godbolt.org/z/jTd8ajYza), which "works" with all the mentioned compilers

```
template<typename C, typename T> struct Item2 {
    void Test() {
    }
};

template<class C> struct Data {
};

template <class C> struct MyData : Data<C> {
    Item2<C, int> item20;
};

struct S;

MyData<S> dataS;
```

It uses a stand-alone template.

How to declare the original template instantiation to conform to the C ++ standard?
The fact that MSVC compiles all 3 options, is a flaw of it?

Comment: The correct answer uses some pretty funky syntax: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/MWMrdPjnd

Comment: @Frank, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few things going wrong here:

```
template <class C> struct MyData : Data<C> {
  MyData::Item1<int> item10;
};
```

`MyData` is an incomplete type here, so we can't use it just yet in that way. However, since `Item1` is inherited from `Data<C>`, we should be able to just refer to it directly:

```
Data<C>::Item1<int> item10;
```

But now, `Data<C>::Item1` is a dependant type, so we need to use `typename` to tell the compiler that it is, in fact, a type:

```
typename Data<C>::Item1<int> item10;
```

Finally, because `Item1` is a template member of a dependant type, we **also** need to tell the compiler that it is a template (as opposed to a constant or something).

```
typename Data<C>::Item1 template<int> item10;
```

So at the end, we land at:

```
template<class C> struct Data {
    template<typename T> struct Item1 {
        void Test() {
        }
    };
};

template <class C> 
struct MyData : Data<C> {
    typename Data<C>::template Item1<int> item10;
};

struct S;

MyData<S> dataS;
```